# NSURLProtocol SWIFT error

Tags: swift, nsurl, nsurlprotocol

I am trying to implement an `NSURLProtocol` in my app that will fetch URLs starting with `myApp://...`

I created the Protocol in a new SWIFT file and implemented in the `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    NSURLProtocol.registerClass(myURLProtocol)
    return true
}
```

But i keep getting this error. I can't figure out how to define the canInitWithRequest to my webViews..

> 2014-08-03 21:10:27.632 SubViewTest[6628:156910] *** WebKit discarded
>   an uncaught exception in the
>   webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:
>   delegate:  *** -canInitWithRequest: only
>   defined for abstract class.  Define -[_TtC11SubViewTest13myURLProtocol
>   canInitWithRequest:]!

Comment: Do you want to open your app from other application?do you looking for url schemes??

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the exception which you've got, `myURLProtocol` class should implement `canInitWithRequest` class function/method; to be precise it should override abstract method of base class.

Here is the annotation-description of `canInitWithRequest` method for `NSURLProtocol` from header file:

```
/*!
@method canInitWithRequest:
@abstract This method determines whether this protocol can handle
the given request.
@discussion A concrete subclass should inspect the given request and
determine whether or not the implementation can perform a load with
that request. This is an abstract method. Sublasses must provide an
implementation. The implementation in this class calls
NSRequestConcreteImplementation.
@param request A request to inspect.
@result YES if the protocol can handle the given request, NO if not.
*/
```

So, the answer is: add code bellow to your `myURLProtocol` class:

```
class func canInitWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest!) -> Bool {
    return true;
}
```

**Remarks:** you might need to examine request object before returning `true` or `false`, just do not forget to add this code :)

Comment: @Tosen, have you tried what I've suggested in answer?